# SELECT COUNT: with mysql_query under conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check the availability of rooms for a specified period for room booking website, but with the following function; if room is unavailable it out puts 101, if available outputs 000; but I want it to be just 1 or 0.

```
function room_unavailable($room_name, $s_at, $e_at){

    $room_name = sanitize($room_name);
//  $s_at = sanitize();
//  $e_at = sanitize();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('room_name') FROM `ordered_rooms` WHERE (`s_at` BETWEEN 7 AND '$e_at') AND (`e_at` BETWEEN '$s_at' AND 18)AND `room_name`= '$room_name'");
    echo (mysql_result($query, 0)); 

}
```

Because I need to return true or false by using `return (mysql_result($q, 0)== 1) ? true: false;`, Instead of `echo (mysql_result($query, 0));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about not selecting a `COUNT` but the simple value `1` from the rows you constrained it to with the `WHERE` then using a `COALESCE` to default to  `0` if no results were returned:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT 1 FROM `ordered_rooms` WHERE (`s_at` BETWEEN 7 AND '$e_at') AND (`e_at` BETWEEN '$s_at' AND 18)AND `room_name`= '$room_name')), 0)
```

Comment: this gives 11, but it is ok for me to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

```
function room_unavailable($room_name, $s_at, $e_at){

    $room_name = sanitize($room_name);
//  $s_at = sanitize();
//  $e_at = sanitize();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('room_name') FROM `ordered_rooms` WHERE (`s_at` BETWEEN 7 AND '$e_at') AND (`e_at` BETWEEN '$s_at' AND 18)AND `room_name`= '$room_name'");

    $res=mysql_result($query, 0); //if this holds 000 or 101
    $res=substr($res,0,1);
    echo $res; // Prints either 1 or 0 depending upon your availability result.

}
```

### The other way..

Instead of

```
return (mysql_result($q, 0)== 1) ? true: false;
```

use

```
return (mysql_result($q, 0)== 1) ? 1:0;
```

Comment: it is still gives 101 of 000

Comment: second one, $res=substr($res,0,1);

Answer (score 0):

```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('room_name') FROM `ordered_rooms` WHERE (`s_at` > 7
   AND `s_at` < '$e_at') AND (`e_at` > '$s_at' AND `e_at` < 18) AND `room_name` LIKE 
   '$room_name'");
```

Comment: this gives 10 and 00 but it is ok too, for me to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('room_name') FROM `ordered_rooms` WHERE (`s_at` BETWEEN 7 AND '".$e_at."') AND (`e_at` BETWEEN '".$s_at."' AND 18)AND `room_name`= '".$room_name."'");
```